# How to read Strings with spaces inside while loop (Java)

Tags: java, while-loop, whitespace, java.util.scanner

This always gives me a headache.  I am trying to read and save multiple-word Strings for the fields "name" and "malady" within a while loop. Here is my code:

```
while(OR1.isFull() == false || OR2.isFull() == false)
{
    // prompt for next request
    System.out.println("Enter patient info:");

    // read patient info
    System.out.print("Name: ");
    String name = input.nextLine();
    input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Malady: ");
    String malady = input.nextLine();
    input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Priority: ");
    int priority = input.nextInt();

    // store patient info
    Patient patient = new Patient(name, malady, priority);

    OR1.add(patient);

} // end while

System.out.println("List of patients scheduled for Operating Room 1");
while(OR1.isEmpty() == false)
{
    // pop and print root
    System.out.print(OR1.remove());
}
```

And here is what my console input and output looks like:

Enter patient info:
Name: John Doe
Malady: Broken hip

Priority: 6

List of patients scheduled for Operating Room 1
Patient:              Malady: Broken hip               Priority:  6

// end console output.

Notice that it did not record the value I entered for "Name," and also that it prompted for an extra line of input after obtaining "Malady" (required me to press enter again to get it to ask for the next input, "Priority").

I have read the documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html.  I have tried different combinations of next() and nextLine(). I just don't get it.

**Problem solved by changing the code to the following:**

```
        // read patient info
        System.out.print("Name: ");
        input.nextLine();
        String name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Malady: ");
        String malady = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Priority: ");
        int priority = input.nextInt();
```

Though I am still confused about how this silly scanner works =/

Comment: How are you setting `name` in the class `Patient`?

Comment: I am not so sure about this, but input.nextLine() reads the last character or String, on the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should work for just:

```
// read patient info
System.out.println("Name: ");
String name = input.nextLine();
System.out.println("Malady: ");
String malady = input.nextLine();
System.out.println("Priority: ");
int priority = input.nextInt();
```

Perhaps the problem is in the Patient constructor or something?

Comment: Fixed! Seee OP (can't answer my own question within 8 hours of posting since my rep is so low).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by changing the code to the following:

```
    // read patient info
    System.out.print("Name: ");
    input.nextLine();
    String name = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Malady: ");
    String malady = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Priority: ");
    int priority = input.nextInt();
```